# Firefox drag to file form element not triggering change event listener

Tags: html, forms, file, firefox, coffeescript

In an HTML form file field, as you may know, you can drag a file and drop it on the 'Choose File' button or the text field displaying the file selected. This selects the file without using the dialog. I was using this behavior, with an invisible and enlarged file field area to simulate a 'drop zone' for instant uploading without the need for HTML5.

I just updated to Firefox 15.0.1, and found out my file field HTML form element is no longer triggering the change event when a file is dropped from the desktop. This continues to function for me in Chrome 21.0.1180.89, and Safari  5.1.6, and was working in Firefox last friday before I updated.

CoffeeScript

```
$ ->
    fileField = document.getElementById 'file-field'
    fileField.addEventListener 'change', file_changed, false
```

The interesting thing is that Firefox is allowing the drag and drop to occur, and thus populating the file field with my file, but since the 'change' event is not triggering, I cannot auto submit the form for the instant upload effect. If anyone has any idea what is going on, or can suggest a lean alternative, I would greatly appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After filing a bug to Mozilla, I was informed the bug had already been reported and it should be fixed in a future release. Just happy they did not intentionally remove this feature!